# Rewrite URLs for SEO friendly with .htaccess on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I'm developing a website using Wordpress (for articles, static pages, ...) but in my theme folder I created a subsystem (handled via php-mysql that doesn't require Wordpress) that uses another database (that contains products). The php page of a single product (`product.php`) is this:

```
<?php
...
if($_GET['url']){
  $url = $_GET['url'];
  $sql = "select * from `products` where url='$url'";
  $row = // start the query ($sql);
  $title=$row[0]['title'];
  $body=$row[0]['body'];
}
else{echo '404 Page.';}
?>

<body>
  <?php 
    echo "<h1>$title</h1>
          <p>$body</p>";
  ?>
</body>
```

And it's rewritten by Wordpress to `product/` in the URL, infact, opening (i.e.) this URL it works:

```
        http://localhost:1234/my-site/product/?url=product-number-one
                                         ^
                                     product.php
```

but I need to rewrite it to this

```
http://localhost:1234/my-site/product/product-number-one
```

.htaccess on Wordpress is by default this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /my-site/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /my-site/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I added to that this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) product?url=$1 [R]
```

but doesn't work. I tried others solutions but nothing done.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is very simple:

```
RewriteRule ^my-site/product/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ /my-site/filename_of_product_page.php?url=$1 [L]
```

With the expression listed within the parentheses, you would need to be sure your url itself matches this- so use a scrubber function when inserting the name into the database.

Comment: Hi @mydoglixu, I added your line and tried to open a product page but it doesn't work: I get "page doesn't exist"

Comment: whoops- i forgot the $ and the .php at the end. of course, you'd need to change the actual filename though...

Comment: Eheh I know, but the problem here is that I can't reach product.php because the page product.php is already rewritten by Wordpress to `product/` in the URL